# create a page for each category automatically in Jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll, categories, jekyll-extensions

### How can I create a page for each category automatically in Jekyll  ?

**example:**

the url of the post : https://UsrNm.github.io/Category1/Category2/2018/02/16/Post1.html

I want when I go to link like:  https://UsrNm.github.io/Category1/Category2/

Get All posts in category `Category1` and `Category2`

or when I go to link like:  https://UsrNm.github.io/Category2/

Get All posts in category `Category2` only

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this automatically.

Well, you have 2 options:

The Jekyll way and the hackish way.

In pure Jekyll way you will need to create pages manually for each category, even if you have posts with multiple categories. Note that Jekyll doesn't have dynamic routing for this.

In hackish way you could use JavaScript to read the parameters in url and show/hide needed content. Idea is to render all of the posts(hidden by default) and create identifiers on them, proper way to do this would be adding html attribute `data-category=cat1` and say that you have url like this `/category?categories=cat1,cat2`. You could then get categories from url and add logic in JavaScript to show just the ones that are actually in that categories.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the gem [jekyll-archives](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-archives) to do this kind of work, which is a plugin of jekyll.

Or if you want to do this manually, you can read this [guide](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/generators/)

You can see the example of [my site](https://jevanwu.github.io/)

Tips: `Github Pages` do not support this. Thus, if you want to deploy this on Github pages, you can convert site to static files and push only `_site` dir to the repo, which has been mentioned at [here](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/installation/) :)